# Problem with "collada_urdf -> Tutorials -> Working Directly with COLLADA"

Tags: ros, rviz, openrave, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to do this tutorial but I don't get the result. No problems appear in console but when rviz start don't show anything, only a black shadow, but in openrave is showing robot correctly.

I try to load several robots in collada (.dae) but no work.

I need to load the mitsubishi-pa10 robot arm in rviz. I'm using this:

```
roslaunch orrosplanning collada_rviz_display.launch
 model:=`rospack find collada_robots`/data/robots/mitsubishi-pa10.dae
```

Thanks,

Raúl

**EDIT:**

Here is the [image of output in rviz](http://www.myupload.org/viewer.php?file=6otjlvdy69o82ap82ww5.png) and the [image of output in openrave](http://www.myupload.org/viewer.php?file=6e9w91kwyzfo2uohhkgj.png).

I can move the robot in openrave and see the movement in rviz but the robot doesn't appear as you can see in the images.

Could be problem of rviz? Do you know a converter from collada to urdf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29180/problem-with-%22collada_urdf--%3E-tutorials--%3E-working-directly-with-collada%22/) by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, it works for me, which version are you using?

```
k-okada@kokada-t420s:~$ rosversion visualization
1.6.7
k-okada@kokada-t420s:~$ rosversion robot_model
1.7.1

...
   [ INFO] [1337139931.344110628]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
   [ INFO] [1337139931.344193801]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
   [ INFO] [1337139931.344222935]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
```

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-20**:
how about updating robot_model? apt-get upgrade will up to date all software.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-20**:
update robot_model?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-20**:
update robot_model?a

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2012-06-24**:
Hi, I'm trying to use the robot_model unstable package but I cannot use it. Because I want to use electric version with only this version in unstable version, but I don't get it.

Could you tell me what version of ROS you are using, please? And, what you did to works?

Thanks!

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2012-06-25**:
I don't understand this. How is possible that you have that versions.
In Electric: robot_model (release is 1.6.4) & visualization (release is 1.6.7)
In Unstable: robot_model (available version is 1.7.1)& visualization (available version is 1.7.4)
Please, could you tell me what version are you using?

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2012-06-25**:
And if you are using a mix of versions, how I can do it. Because I've been looking for how to do on Internet and I haven't found it. Thanks!

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-06-25**:
I use electric, plus robot_model from source. if you use rosws(http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws), try $ echo "[{hg: {local-name: robot_model, uri: 'http://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/\
robot_model', version:f342b5c73a7f}]" | rosws merge -
$ rosws update robot_model